# Lending Club website not allowing me to login through CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download the loans stat files from lending club. They offer two versions of the file a secure version and a regular one. In order to download the secure version I have to be logged in.

The url reads something like:
https://resources.lendingclub.com/secure/LoanStats3a_securev1.csv.zip?signature=foo&issued=bar

Both "signature" and "issued" seem to change each time I login and browse to the page.

My solution is to login to the site, go to the download page and get the full url with the query string.

I tried the following code to login:

```
$username = "myemail@example.com";
$password = "mypassword";

$url='https://www.lendingclub.com/account/login.action?login_email='.$username.'&login_password='.$password;
$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

var_dump($httpcode);
var_dump($result);
return;
```

I get a http response of 200. And

```
int(200) string(32454) "    
This website does not support this version of Internet Explorer. Please upgrade to the latest version for a better experience. Upgrade Now
...
```

I got the user agent string by sniffing the header when I access the site in my browser.

I spent a good part of the afternoon googling and trying to find a way around this problem. I tried with cookies and it didn't work.

Any ideas on what else I can try?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few more things I was finally able to find a solution for my issue.

I am posting it here for reference in case someone has a similar problem in the future:

I was trying to login to Lending Club using my login credentials (username and password) in the first cURL request. The site didn't allow me to login and kept redirecting me to the login screen.

My solution was to use 2 cURL requests. The first one to the login page without my credentials. I did it so I could save the cookie set by the site. Then I used that cookie in my second cURL request - this one with my login credentials. It worked.

See below the working code:

```
$cookie = 'cookie.txt';
$url = 'https://www.lendingclub.com/account/login.action';

//first cURL request - no login credentials. Used only to get the cookie from site.
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); // Stores cookies in the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);

//second cURL request - with login credentials. Added cookie obtained from first cURL request above.
$fields = array( 
    'login_email' => 'email@example.com', 
    'login_password' => 'mypassword', 
);
$fields_string = ''; 
foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
{ 
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&'); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Accepts all CAs 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); //Uses cookies from the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); // Stores cookies in the temp file 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Tells cURL to follow redirects 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Also, I am still receiving the message that the website does not support this version of Internet Explorer. But it seems to be only a warning. I am still able to login.

Thanks.

Comment: Interested in what you are doing / have done. I am working on something very similar using java. Would love to chat with you.